# Error MySQL #1064 at 1 Line

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I need to create table for my sql database and i have a 1 error sucking my work, anyone can help me for i fix that error:

```
[sql]CREATE TABLE `z_ots_comunication` (
`id` int(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`action` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`delete_it` int(2) NOT NULL default '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Msg of MySQL:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[sql]CREATE TABLE `z_ots_comunication` (
>   `id` int(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
>   `name`' at line 1

Comment: Where did the `[sql]` at the start originate from? That is the source of the error, as MySQL plainly states, and is not part of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax for MySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Try a comma at the end of the line

Comment: And there's a missing comma at the end of the `id` definition, before the `name` definition begins. Fix those things, and [your table will create successfully](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75442)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `user` ( 
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
`username` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
`regdate` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL , 
`website` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL , 
`show_email` INT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`last_login` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL 
)

I changed for that code and solved the problem, thanks for help guy! =')

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a comma after the ID column:

```
CREATE TABLE `z_ots_comunication` (
`id` int(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
...
```

Comment: I solved it changed my code for this:

CREATE TABLE `user` ( 
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
`regdate` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL , 
`website` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL , 
`show_email` INT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`last_login` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL 
)

Thanos for Help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try This code u have missed a semi colon before name filed

```
CREATE TABLE `z_ots_comunication` (
`id` int(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`action` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param6` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`param7` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`delete_it` int(2) NOT NULL default '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```